# What am I doing wrong with making the theme 'dark' to make it save theme after switching between parts of the site

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to use local storage to make the theme stay after you switch parts of the site but I can't get it to work. Here's my js

```
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggleDark');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
localStorage.getItem('theme')
localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')


toggle.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
   this.classList.toggle('bi-moon');
    
   if(this.classList.toggle('bi-brightness-high-fill')){ 
       
       body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image/background.jpg")'
       body.style.color = 'beige';
       
       body.style.transition = '2s';
       localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')
       isDark = !Boolean(isDark);
       
    }else{
            
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image/lightestBackground.jpg")'
        body.style.color = '#222222';
        body.style.transition = '2s';
        localStorage.removeItem('dark');
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant html

```
<i class="bi bi-moon" id="toggleDark" alt="Moon" aria-label="Change color theme"></i>
```

I have tried using multiple setItems so having a light and dark item and also messed around with the set and get item. If you can help or give me any tips that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Please add your HTML code too.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems here.

First, you should store the theme as a boolean instead of adding or removing the word "dark".  This way you always have a state saved, and then you can just get a boolean out of it and use that in your code.

You have an `if` statement evaluating `this.classList.toggle('bi-brightness-high-fill')` which is not a boolean.  You should set this elsewhere and have the `if` evaluate the boolean instead.  You can actually pass a boolean into the `toggle()` method, so we can use that here too!

The main problem is that you are only making style changes to you page when you click on the element.  When the page first runs, nothing makes any UI changes.  So you fix this, put the code that changes the UI into a function, and call that when you click the button, but also call it immediately when the page loads.

Here is my solution:

```js
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggleDark');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

//Get the initial value and save it to a vaiable
//If there is no value yet, default it to false
const storageKey = 'darkTheme';
const initialValue = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
let isDark = initialValue != null ? /^true$/i.test(initialValue) : false;

function setThemeUi(){
  //Toggle button classes based in the isDark value
  toggle.classList.toggle('bi-moon', isDark);
  toggle.classList.toggle('bi-brightness-high-fill', isDark);

  //Apply other styles based on isDark
  if(isDark){    
    body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image/background.jpg")'
    body.style.color = 'beige';
    body.style.transition = '2s';
  }else{
    body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image/lightestBackground.jpg")'
    body.style.color = '#222222';
    body.style.transition = '2s';
  }
}

toggle.addEventListener('click', function(){
  //toggle the value and save it to storage
  isDark = !isDark;
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, isDark);
  
  //Change the UI based on the new value
  setThemeUi();
});

//Set the UI based on the theme initially, before a click
setThemeUi();
```

---

However, it's bad practice to set CSS in the JS like that, so a better solution would be to have some CSS classes like this:

```css
.theme-light{
  background-image: url("image/lightestBackground.jpg");
  color: #222222;
  transition: 2s;
}

.theme-dark{
  background-image: url("image/background.jpg");
  color: beige;
}
```

and then use this for the JS

```js
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggleDark');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

//Get the initial value and save it to a vaiable
//If there is no value yet, default it to false
const storageKey = 'darkTheme';
const initialValue = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
let isDark = initialValue != null ? /^true$/i.test(initialValue) : false;

function setThemeUi(){
  //Toggle button classes based in the isDark value
  toggle.classList.toggle('bi-moon', isDark);
  toggle.classList.toggle('bi-brightness-high-fill', isDark);
  body.classList.toggle('theme-light', !isDark);
  body.classList.toggle('theme-dark', isDark);
}

toggle.addEventListener('click', function(){
  //toggle the value and save it to storage
  isDark = !isDark;
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, isDark);
  
  //Change the UI based on the new value
  setThemeUi();
});

//Set the UI based on the theme initially, before a click
setThemeUi();
```

Comment: When I use the first JS you suggested the button doesn't change between the icons and the theme doesn't change. For the icons I am going through BootStrap Icons so maybe that's messing it up because the icons arent local. But thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure which theme you wanted the icons to appear on, so you might need to switch the logic on those.  Open up your developer tools and inspect that element and see if the correct classes are being applied or not.  If they are, then it's probably the issue you just mentioned.